# Android: Drag and Drop Images

Tags: java, android, drag-and-drop

I have this "Drag and Drop" thingy.

So basically we are making a prototype to let the user (kid) to drag and drop the candy to a jar.

These are the code I have been researching for a while

```
package edu.sbcc.cs123.draganddropbasic;

import android.app.*;
import android.graphics.*;
import android.os.*;
import android.view.*;
import android.view.View.*;
import android.widget.*;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public class DragAndDropBasicActivity extends Activity implements OnTouchListener {
    private ImageView letterView;                       // The letter that the user drags.
    private ImageView emptyLetterView;              // The letter outline that the user is supposed to drag letterView to.
    private AbsoluteLayout mainLayout;


    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        mainLayout = (AbsoluteLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);
        mainLayout.setOnTouchListener(this);
        letterView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.letterView);
        letterView.setOnTouchListener(this);

        emptyLetterView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.emptyLetterView);
    }

    private boolean dragging = false;
    private Rect hitRect = new Rect();

    @Override
    /**
     * NOTE:  Had significant problems when I tried to react to ACTION_MOVE on letterView.   Kept getting alternating (X,Y) 
     * locations of the motion events, which caused the letter to flicker and move back and forth.  The only solution I could 
     * find was to determine when the user had touched down on the letter, then process moves in the ACTION_MOVE 
     * associated with the mainLayout.
     */
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        boolean eventConsumed = true;
        int x = (int)event.getX();
        int y = (int)event.getY();

        int action = event.getAction();
        if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            if (v == letterView) {
                dragging = true;
                eventConsumed = false;
            }
        } else if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {

            if (dragging) {
                emptyLetterView.getHitRect(hitRect);
                if (hitRect.contains(x, y))
                    setSameAbsoluteLocation(letterView, emptyLetterView);
            }
            dragging = false;
            eventConsumed = false;

        } else if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
            if (v != letterView) {
                if (dragging) {
                    setAbsoluteLocationCentered(letterView, x, y);
                }
            }
        }

        return eventConsumed;

    }


    private void setSameAbsoluteLocation(View v1, View v2) {
        AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams alp2 = (AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams) v2.getLayoutParams();
        setAbsoluteLocation(v1, alp2.x, alp2.y);
    }


    private void setAbsoluteLocationCentered(View v, int x, int y) {
        setAbsoluteLocation(v, x - v.getWidth() / 2, y - v.getHeight() / 2);
    }


    private void setAbsoluteLocation(View v, int x, int y) {
        AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams alp = (AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams) v.getLayoutParams();
        alp.x = x;
        alp.y = y;
        v.setLayoutParams(alp);
    }
}
```

these are for the main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<AbsoluteLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:id="@+id/mainLayout">

<ImageView 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:id="@+id/emptyLetterView" 
    android:src="@drawable/candy" 
    android:layout_x="200px" 
    android:layout_y="300px"></ImageView>

<ImageView 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:id="@+id/letterView" 
    android:src="@drawable/candy1" >

</ImageView>
</AbsoluteLayout>
```

However, I want to add other candies to be dragged also. How can I implement this?

Comment: You only have 2 candies. What do you mean other candies? Could you elaborate on what you want?

Comment: Oh sorry. In that code, I have tried that the "candy1" is the one which can be dragged, the "candy" is the dropped position. So I wanna add another candy say "candy2" which has the same functionality to "candy1" (can be dragged, too) I have done the same thing which is, assigned the android:id to "@+id/letterView", but it does nothing. It can't be even dragged.

Comment: So in other words, it can only work with one candy. how should I edit the code so that it can work with many candies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay since, your a beginner I'll go through this thoroughly.

The method you have chosen is not ideal for what you're attempting and you might be better of with a custom view and using the Canvas.

However you can still do what you want with this method (and it would avoid a re-write)

The problem here is you have one `ImageView` when you want multiple instances of it.

So since you want multiple instances create them dynamically first remove candy from your XML file and then follow this code

```
ImageView[] candies = new ImageView[10];
 for(int i=0;i<candies.length;i++){
      candies[i]=new ImageView(this);
      // TODO: Set LayoutParams for each imageView
      // i.e. AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams imageParams1 = new AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams(imageWidth, imageHeight); 

     candies[i].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.candy); 
     layout.addView(candies[i], imageParams1);
}
```

Now you have 'n' number of candies added to your screen you need to be able to move them.

Your code for the `onTouch` will now need to be edited.

Now instead of `boolean dragging` make dragging an `int` indicating which view is being dragged.

Also instead of

```
setSameAbsoluteLocation(letterView, emptyLetterView);
```

use

```
setSameAbsoluteLocation(v, emptyLetterView);
```

so the code will work for all views listening (i.e. all the candies). Do this in all `letterView` locations in `MOUSE_UP` and `MOUSE_DOWN`

Now in your `MOUSE_MOVE` you'll have to do something like this to drag appropriate view

```
if (v != letterView) {
    if (dragging!=-1) {
        setAbsoluteLocationCentered(letterView[dragging], x, y);
     }
}
```

Comment: Where should I put the `ImageView[] candies = new ImageView[10];` ?

Comment: Put it in onCreate after the super call

Comment: Carl, I have started a new question. Can you look at it? I have changed the dragging method. [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14291752/image-drop-and-drag] Royally thank you for all your help!